# Swift: How do I wait until a variable has a certain value

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to write code that waits until a variable equals a certain value.  Here is the code I have written:

```
    var i = 0

    for i in 1...10 {
        playtrial()
        repeat {

        } while (WasItCorrect=="")

    WasItCorrect = ""
    }
```

The idea is that the function will call playtrial, wait until the variable WasItCorrect has a value (other than ""),  reset WasItCorrect, and then repeat (for a total of 10 times).

The code produces no errors.  However, after plastral is done, the program seems to stop responding and does not allow any new input / button pressing.

I assume the problem is that my repeat/while loop goes forever and never gives a chance for anything else to happen and therefore other functions which change the value of WasItCorrect cannot run.  As a VisualBasic 6 programmer who is just starting to learn Swift, I would guess I would need the Swift version of DoEvents.  Is that true?

Any advice on how to fix this code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `didSet` property of the variable. It will be called whenever the value changed.

```
var i = 0 {
    didSet {
        print("Hello World.")
        if i == certainValue {
         // do something
        }
    }
}
```